# How to calculate like a spreadsheet of excel in Linux?

Tags: linux, spreadsheet

I have a table

```
A 1 1 1 
B 2 2 2 
C 3 3 3
```

I want to create a new row of "sum" like

```
A 1 1 1 
B 2 2 2 
C 3 3 3 
SUM 6 6 6
```

and new columns running this formula value/sum to get

```
A 1 1 1 0.17 0.17 0.17
B 2 2 2 0.33 0.33 0.33
C 3 3 3 0.5 0.5 0.5
SUM 6 6 6
```

The above is a simplified example and actually, I have a much bigger table.

How to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: https://www.libreoffice.org/

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: you have also R, sagemath.

Comment: What about [`sc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sc_(spreadsheet_calculator))

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do spreadsheets in linux, your go-to option is [Libre Office](http://libreoffice.org), an open source and open standards equivalent of the Microsoft Office suite.

It can even read `.xls` spreadsheets, although it will refuse to execute most macros unless you absolutely insist on them.

Comment: N.B. LibreOffice can not only read xls (or xlsx for that matter), it can also write these formats. Moreover, modern MS Office suites can read ods.

Comment: Yes, but I was answering his question, not writing an advertisement for libreoffice. It's doing quite well on its own merits.